# How to get the path source of bitmap in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to get the path of an image which is feeding an already created bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using the reference of the `Image` control on **Windows Phone** but you can get it from the model it's binded to.